# Problems Downloading Server 12.10

Tags: 12.10, iso

I've been trying to download the ISO for Server 12.10 amd64 for a week now.  None of the MD5 checksums match the posted values.  I am not having any problems downloading from other sites, and I've tried the download from multiple computers.

Answer (score 1):

The MD5sum of the server file is 4bd3270bde86d7e4e017e3847a4af485 *ubuntu-12.10-server-amd64.iso and the .ISO is found here http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-server-amd64.iso

according to http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/

Answer (score 0):

Try torrenting the files from the .torrent files on the site.  The BitTorrent protocol has built in file checking, so your likelihood of a corrupted download is much lower - plus, file download speeds will most likely be faster!